# Getting only value from PHP JSON array (why do I have to use implode?)

Tags: php, arrays, json

Okay, so I'm fairly new to PHP but it's enough like JS so I've been picking it up fairly quickly.

One issue I ran into the other day was getting the values from a JSON file.

My JSON file is 30,000 lines, but here's essentially what it looks like:

```
{
    "congress": {
        "Brown Sherrod": [{
            "birthday": "1952-11-09"
        }, {
            "gender": "M"
        }, {
            "type": "sen"
        }, {
            "state": "OH"
        }, {
            "party": "Democrat"
        }],
        ...
```

And anyway, it continues like that for another 29,000 + lines. My code to get the contents of the JSON file is this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/file/convertcsv.json'), true);
```

It returns an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [birthday] => 1952-11-09
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [gender] => M
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [type] => sen
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [state] => OH
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [party] => Democrat
    )
)
```

My issue I ran into is that I can't get the value of, say, ['birthday'] without using `implode()`.

This works: `$state = implode($data['congress'][$nameInput][3]);`, but this does not: `$state = $data['congress'][$nameInput][3];`

Is there a reason why? I've read the docs on `implode()` (join array elements with string) and from what I gather from SO and the PHP docs this is how you get the value, but *why*? It makes no sense to have to convert the array to a string in order to get the value. In JavaScript to get the value from an array (or even a key-value) you just use the ['key'] or the [index] of the array, and it'll give you the value.

I feel like either I'm goofing on something major (not unlikely) or PHP is just weird -- probably the former. So, to reiterate my question (because I can ramble) **am I making this too complex or is PHP just weird (and if so, is there a reason)?**

Comment: Seems odd to stuff each key/value pair into an array entry. Would be much easier to work with `"Brown Sherrod": { "birthday": "1952-11-09", "gender": "M", ...}`

Comment: @Phil thanks for your edit. I always have trouble formatting posts. I tried to do that, but trying to format a 30,000 line JSON file that was broken to begin with was nearly impossible so once I got it to validate I ran with it. I might just wrestle with it a bit longer...

Comment: @Phil I should also mention that I had to move the name of each person (e.g. "Brown Sherrod") **out** of each array so I could use that as the identifier instead of how it originally came where it was using other identifiers that weren't as easy to access... a few regexps later I finally fixed *most* of the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below :-

```
$state = $data['congress'][$nameInput][3]['state']
```

Comment: Have you ever had one of those moments when you're chatting on the phone with a friend while frantically looking for your phone and you're freaking out because you can't find it? This is kind of like that, but with code. Thanks :-)